# simple products will not add to configurable

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

When I programmatically create configurable and simples product, all is created but simple products do not add to configurable. The code works well, without errors in log. Can you help me?

```
    /*************  simple **************/    
$n_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
for($vel=35; $vel<43; $vel++) 
    {
    if(!$n_product->getIdBySku($sku."-".$vel))
        {
        if ($vel == 35) { $vel_id = 549; }
        if ($vel == 36) { $vel_id = 550; }
        if ($vel == 37) { $vel_id = 551; }
        if ($vel == 38) { $vel_id = 552; }
        if ($vel == 39) { $vel_id = 553; }
        if ($vel == 40) { $vel_id = 554; }
        if ($vel == 41) { $vel_id = 555; }
        if ($vel == 42) { $vel_id = 556; }
        $n_product->setSku($sku."-".$vel);
        $n_product->setName($sku."-".$vel);
        $n_product->setAttributeSetId($atIDS);
        $n_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $n_product->setStatus(1);
        $n_product->setWeight(1000);
        $n_product->setVisibility(2);
        $n_product->setTaxClassId(2);
        $n_product->setTypeId('simple');
        $n_product->setPrice($cena);
        $n_product->setSpecialPrice($cena_akcni);
        $n_product->setStockData(array('use_config_manage_stock' => 0,'manage_stock' => 1,'is_in_stock' => 1,'qty' => 1));
        $n_product->setSize($vel_id);
        $n_product->save();
        $simpleProductArr[] = $n_product->getId();
        $logger->info("Simple product ".$vel.": ".$simpleProductArr[]);
        }
    }
/*************  configurable **************/
if(!$n_product->getIdBySku($sku)) 
    {
    $n_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    if ($kategorie == 'Dámské válenky') { $n_product->setAttributeSetId($atIDS); $n_product->setCategoryIds(array(3,4,324)); }
    if ($kategorie == 'Dámské lodičky') { $n_product->setAttributeSetId($atIDS); $n_product->setCategoryIds(array(3,4,29)); }
    if ($kategorie == 'Dámské tenisky') { $n_product->setAttributeSetId($atIDS); $n_product->setCategoryIds(array(3,4,30)); }               
    if ($kategorie == 'Dámské sandále') { $n_product->setAttributeSetId($atIDS); $n_product->setCategoryIds(array(3,4,31)); }
    $n_product->setSku($sku);
    $n_product->setName($nazev);
    $n_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $n_product->setStatus(1);
    $n_product->setWeight(1000);
    $n_product->setVisibility(2);
    $n_product->setTaxClassId(2);
    $n_product->setTypeId('configurable');
    $n_product->setPrice($cena);
    $n_product->setSpecialPrice($cena_akcni);
    $n_product->setStockData(array('use_config_manage_stock' => 0,'manage_stock' => 1,'is_in_stock' => 1,'qty' => 1));
    $n_product->setMetaTitle($nazev);
    $n_product->setMetaKeyword($popis);
    $n_product->setMetaDescription($popis);
    $n_product->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(206),$n_product);
    $configurableAttributesData = $n_product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($n_product);
    $n_product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $n_product->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $simpleProducts = $productCollection->addIdFilter($simpleProductArr)->addAttributeToSelect('size')->addAttributeToSelect('price');
    $configurableProductsData = array();
    foreach ($simpleProducts as $simple)
        {
        $logger->info("Info: ".$simple->getAttributeText('size')."-".$simple->getSize()."-".$simple->getPrice()."-".$simple->getId());
        $productData = array(
            'label' => $simple->getAttributeText('size'),
            'attribute_id' => 206,
            'value_index' => (int) $simple->getSize(),
            'is_percent' => 0,
            'pricing_value' => $simple->getPrice());
        $configurableProductsData[$simple->getId()] = $productData;
        }
    $n_product->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
    $n_product->save();
    }
```

Comment: What is the magento version your using?

Comment: See the namespace this instantly tells you its magento 2 something.  the version is irrelivant as long as you use the factories and interfaces not the models which are deprecated.

Comment: Magento ver. 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

bellow is the quickest way to add configurable product link to a product loaded via product repository, so save your base configurable product first.

```
   $attributeValues[] = [
                'label' => $optionLabel,
                'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
                'value_index' =>  $config['product']->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()),
            ];

            $configurableAttributesData = [
                [
                    'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId(),
                    'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                    'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                    'position' => '0',
                    'values' => $attributeValues,
                ],
            ];
```

From your simple products populate two arrays like above to pass to the configurable product.

```
  $extensionConfigurableAttributes = $p->getExtensionAttributes();
        $childrenIds = $p->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds( $p->getId());

        if(is_array($childrenIds)) {
            if(isset($childrenIds[0])) {
                $associatedProductIds = array_unique(array_merge($associatedProductIds, $childrenIds[0]));
            }
        }

        // die(var_dump($associatedProductIds, $extensionConfigurableAttributes->getConfigurableProductLinks()));
        $configurableOptions = $this->optionsFactory->create($configurableAttributesData);

        $extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductOptions($configurableOptions);
        $extensionConfigurableAttributes->setConfigurableProductLinks($associatedProductIds);


        $p->setExtensionAttributes($extensionConfigurableAttributes);
```

And then simply save the product like below. This will work for both create and update, and will not create duplicate groups.

```
   $p = $this->productRepository->save($p);
```

Comment: Sorry man, I dont understand this. Can you explain me?